# PHP if / else statements don't seem to work for contact us with email

Tags: statements

I've created some if / else statements to get a download when a user hit click 
but dont work ,because you can direct download without field name or email ,please help me
contact. php for my site 
http://my-easy-woodworking-projects.com

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'lulu@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script>

var str = "download";
document.write(str.link("http://www.myshedplans.com/12BY8SHED.pdf"));

</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-help.com');
        window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: be more clear besides "it doesn't work".  whats the output? is there an error?  what does the html look like when you are done?

Comment: Note for readability:  if you use double quotes you can embed variables in strings without using "." (concat.)  For example:  $headers = "From: $field_email \r\n";

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why that if/else isn't working for you but one thing that can happen is the interpreter forgets about the if statement when it gets down to the else.  A way to get around this is by echoing your html code within the conditional block like bellow:

```
<?php
    if ($mail_status) {
        echo "<script>";
        echo "var str = \"download\";";
        echo "document.write(str.link(\"http://www.myshedplans.com/12BY8SHED.pdf\"));";
        echo "</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
        echo "alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-help.com');";
        echo "window.location = 'contact_page.html';";
        echo "</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: when i put your code ,their is nothing happen ,a page white only when i field name and when i hit download without field name and email